# Export to Excel from multiple dataTables

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have 5 grid view in various tabs of a form and i need to show all those data which are in different tab to a single excel sheet or in  a workbook.

Comment: please help me to figure it out friends

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all datables in single dataset by putting following lines in code.

```
Dataset.Tables.Add(DataTable)
```

once your dataset is prepared then you can export it via EXCEL COM Component with following code.

```
public class WorkbookEngine
{
public static void CreateWorkbook(DataSet ds, String path)
{
XmlDataDocument xmlDataDoc = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
XslTransform xt = new XslTransform();
StreamReader reader =new StreamReader(typeof (WorkbookEngine).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(typeof (WorkbookEngine), “Excel.xsl”));
XmlTextReader xRdr = new XmlTextReader(reader);
xt.Load(xRdr, null, null);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
xt.Transform(xmlDataDoc, null, sw, null);
StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter (path + “\\Report.xls”);
myWriter.Write (sw.ToString());
myWriter.Close ();
}
}
```

refer following link for further details

http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support/articles/import-export-dataset-xls-xlsx-ods-csv-html-net